# How do I make load data infile give an error

Tags: mysql, load-data-infile

Is there a way to verify in MySQL that the file contains all the columns that it is supposed to when uploading a csv file?

Currently for some reason when I upload my file to mysql it doesn't give an error when I upload a file with to few columns.

My query:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'path/file.csv'
into table raw
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '
'
(x1,
  x2,
  x3)
```

I would like this to give an error when uploading a file with only 2 columns. Is this possible?

Comment: MySQL doesn't care, and I don't think you can make it.

Comment: The MySQL philosophy has always been "close enough" instead of striving for adherence to standards or accuracy. Most of the time it does what you want, but it also does a pretty crappy job of catching mistakes.